# Hiding the Keyboard triggered by textField via resignFirstResponder

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, textfield

Environment: Xcode Version 8.2 (8C38)/Swift 3.0

A **textFiled** object in the View is wire up to a method named **textFieldReturn** in the controller via IBAction. The related codes are presented as follow

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

@IBAction func textFieldReturn(_ sender: Any) {
        _ = (sender as AnyObject).resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

**What I expect**:

When I hit the **Return** key of the virtual keyboard the function textFieldReturn(_:) will be called and the keyboard will be hidden

**Issue Observer**:

The function is not called after I tapped the return key, the keyboard is still there

**Resource**:

This code spinet come from the example of the Chapter 16 of the book iOS 10 App Development Essentials by ***Neil Symth*** (pp-114)

The only difference between this code and original code is the type of the function argument (Sender). It is **AnyObject** in the original book while I've got **Any** by default, therefore I've cast to **AnyObject** inside the function body

**Question**:

Its seems to be a decent book, but the sample code doesn't work for me. How can I call the **resignFirstResponder()** method when I hit the return key

---

**Alternative try out**:

Instead of using **IBAction**, I turn to the idea of delegate, I've set the **VeiwController** as the delegate of the **textField**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tempText: UITextField! //reference the TextField as the variable **tempText** in the controller  

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tempText.delegate = self //set up the delegation 
    }

    func textFieldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return(true)
    }
}
```

**Problem**

The alternative solution still not working.

Thanks for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you not using the original delegate function of `UITextField`?

I think the default function will work as you want:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tempText: UITextField! //reference the TextField as the variable **tempText** in the controller  

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tempText.delegate = self //set up the delegation 
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool{
        textField.resignFirstResponder()

        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: So there is a original delegate function, thanks so much, I didn't know there is a default function for this, thanks so so much.

Comment: But why the first one which using the IBAction way is not working?

Comment: The function textFieldShouldReturn is always called whenever your keyboard's return key is pressed. So no other method will work.

Comment: so that's the only way to hide the keyboard by tap the return key

Comment: No there are so many different ways too. But if you are pressing the return key of keyboard then only it will work. Otherwise there are so many ways to hide keyboard based on the different event.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your textFieldReturn method with this and it should work just fine.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
}
```

Make sure to keep the following in your viewDidLoad()

```
self.tempText.delegate = self
```